# How can I split and concat a string while using intermediate result?

Tags: java, java-stream

Let's san I have a String looks like

```
a/b/c/d
```

I need to process some job(MKCOL) for following values in a row.

```
a
a/b
a/b/c
a/b/c/d
```

I know I can split and using them concatenating one by one.

Is there any way to do this with stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is:

```
String s = "a/b/c/d";
String[] array = s.split("/");
for (int i = 1; i <= array.length; i++) {
    String part = Arrays.stream(array).limit(i).collect(Collectors.joining("/"));
    System.out.println(part);
}
```